# r - ratio calculation via data set

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
df$countryName = as.character(df$countryName)
```

I processed the dataset.

```
df$countryName[df$countryName == "United States"] <- "United States of America"
```

Changed here for United States of America Arrived in population data.

```
df8$death_pop <- df8$death / df8$PopTotal
```

I totally calculated the death/pop.

most, 10 countries. death/pop. how can I find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base R`:

```r
df8[order(df8$death_pop, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10],]
```

This orders your data.frame by death_pop and extracts the first 10 rows.

Using the package `dplyr` there is the function `top_n`, which gives you the desired result. I added `arrange(desc()` to give you a sorted output. Remove this part if you don't need it.

```r
df8 %>% top_n(10, death_pop) %>% arrange(desc(death_pop))
```